# API design question on File and InputStream parameter

Tags: java, api

can I consider File as a special case of InputStream and provide 1 API like

```
 test(InputStream stream)
```

or two overloaded APIs are better

```
test(File f)
test(InputStream stream)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file is certainly not an input stream. It can be used to *create* an input stream, but it's not one itself.

Note that the overloads you've given have a fundamentally different character - the method accepting `File` needn't change any state, but the method accepting `InputStream` almost certainly would. Also, assuming they're going to do something similar internally, the `File` method would want to close the stream opened in the method; the `InputStream` method *wouldn't* want to close the stream, because it doesn't "own" it.

That's okay - it may well be fine to have these two methods anyway - but you need to be aware of the difference.

Another option is to use the [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) library and take an [`InputSupplier<InputStream>`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/io/InputSupplier.html) - then callers can use `Files.newInputStreamSupplier(file)` to specify the stream, but could also use a supplier of network-related input streams, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Providing an API that accepts an `InputStream` is probably the most general approach in this area.

If the API will often/sometimes be called with the goal of loading from files, then providing an additional overload that accepts `File` can be advantageous.

In the end it boils down to how often something will be used: adding an additional overloaded method doesn't cost much, but if your API is littered with unused methods, it can get less elegant.

Answer (score 0):

And what about this as the only method:

```
test(URL url)
```

? Now your API is capable of handling files on the filesystem, HTTP/FTP resources, CLASSPATH resources (see [`ClassLoader.getResource()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)), and much more out of the box (the supported protocols are actually pluggable).

Just call [`URL.openConnection()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29)`.getInputStream();`